# Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ". DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, sqljdbc

I am in the middle of a project to update my application's code base from Java 1.6 to Java 1.8, and something I did is causing the following error when I try to connect to the database:

`DataSource Configuration: DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource jdbc/TIRDB.  Encountered java.sql.SQLException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ". DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0.`

I am using Websphere 8.5.5.9 and sqljdbc4, and the database was recently updated to SQL server 2017.

Solutions I have already tried:

- adding "-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true" to the JVM arguments
- updating the sqljdbc driver to 8.4
- Modifying the java.security file to remove 3DES_EDE_CBC

If I've left out any important information please let me know, I can edit the post.

EDIT:

I added the following JVM command to gain more information: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose

In the logs I see the following information:

> [1/19/21 12:20:43:698
> CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O *** ClientHello, TLSv1 [1/19/21
> 12:20:43:698 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O RandomCookie:  GMT:
> 1611080187 bytes = { 202, 165, 173, 127, 167, 84, 140, 203, 125, 176,
> 234, 88, 28, 249, 55, 235, 125, 139, 218, 189, 60, 181, 119, 214, 251,
> 102, 209, 42 } [1/19/21 12:20:43:700 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O
> Session ID:  {} [1/19/21 12:20:43:700 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O
> Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV,
> SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
> SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA] [1/19/21 12:20:43:700 CST] 0000004a
> SystemOut     O Compression Methods:  { 0 } [1/19/21 12:20:43:700 CST]
> 0000004a SystemOut     O Extension elliptic_curves, curve names:
> {secp256r1, secp192r1, secp224r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, secp160k1,
> secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, secp224k1, secp256k1} [1/19/21
> 12:20:43:700 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O Extension ec_point_formats,
> formats: [uncompressed] [1/19/21 12:20:43:700 CST] 0000004a SystemOut
> O *** [1/19/21 12:20:43:701 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O
> server.startup : 2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 109 [1/19/21
> 12:20:43:730 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, called
> close() [1/19/21 12:20:43:730 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O
> server.startup : 2, called closeInternal(true) [1/19/21 12:20:43:730
> CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:
> warning, description = close_notify [1/19/21 12:20:43:730 CST]
> 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert,
> length = 2 [1/19/21 12:20:43:730 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O
> server.startup : 2, called closeSocket(true) [1/19/21 12:20:43:730
> CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, waiting for
> close_notify or alert: state 5 [1/19/21 12:20:43:731 CST] 0000004a
> SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, received EOFException: ignored
> [1/19/21 12:20:43:731 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup :
> 2, called closeInternal(false) [1/19/21 12:20:43:731 CST] 0000004a
> SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, close invoked again; state = 5
> [1/19/21 12:20:43:731 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup :
> 2, handling exception: java.io.IOException: SQL Server did not return
> a response. The connection has been closed.
> ClientConnectionId:e3180c28-baa6-4741-8359-008575b697b3 [1/19/21
> 12:20:43:731 CST] 0000004a SystemOut     O server.startup : 2, called
> closeSocket()
> Blockquote

I think this indicates my server is still using TLSv1, even though the database is set up to only accept TSL1.2.  I have tried adding JVM commands -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 and -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to force it to use TLSv1.2 but it did not change.

Comment: Probably caused by upgrading SQL server.  The 8.5.5.9 WebSphere is scary old (December 2015) and that means the Java you have WebSphere running on is probably that old or even older, possibly even Java 6! After you upgrade at least WebSphere and its Java ... its possible it might just work with the latest sqljdbc driver, and you probably want to keep  "-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true".  From an SSL perspective, WebSphere has control of how SSL starts but the JDBC driver has control of how the connection is made, you could get an SSL trace https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/707663

Comment: I had to update Websphere to 8.5.5.9 in order to change the server to run on java 8, which is what it is currently using.  There are newer versions of Websphere available I think, but I am not using them right now.  I am using sqljdbc 8.4, which I believe is the newest version.  My co-workers are still running java 6 using websphere 8.5.5.5 which does not support java 8, and they were able to connect to the SQL 2017 server using the overrideDefaultTLS JVM argument.  The fact that it isn't working for me tells me something else has gone wrong, but I haven't been able to find any leads.

Comment: 8.5.5.9 might have been an upgrade, from 8.5.5.5 but running either now is not a good idea, because both are so old they expose you to Many security vulnerabilities, and there have been a lot of fixes / tweaks to behavior ... to keep moving forward with other changes... and that might be what is tripping you up now, the changes in WebSphere code between 8.5.5.5 and 8.5.5.9... but most likely the changes between Java 6 and Java 8, the SSL engine is in the Java base.  You should run that SSL trace on the co-workers system and yours and focus on what is different in leading up to the failure.

Comment: So if the database connection is being attempted using a particular protocol like TLSv1.0 and you want it to use TLSv1.2 ... it is not under the control of the WebSphere Application Server SSL configuration or QoP etc.  The protocol used is COMPLETELY under control of the database driver.  Why you would set overrideDefaultTLS is described here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html